# Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory | Express | HBS instead of handlebars.js

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

[view-engine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urGYg.png)

I have installed hbs instead of handlebar for dynamic templating, and now I'm stuck at this problem.

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "/home/trijay/Desktop/NodeJs/web-server/src/views"
    at Function.render (/home/trijay/Desktop/NodeJs/web-server/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:580:17)
    at ServerResponse.render (/home/trijay/Desktop/NodeJs/web-server/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1008:7)
    at app.get (/home/trijay/Desktop/NodeJs/web-server/src/app.js:14:9)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/trijay/Desktop/NodeJs/web-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/trijay/Desktop/NodeJs/web-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/trijay/Desktop/NodeJs/web-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/trijay/Desktop/NodeJs/web-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/trijay/Desktop/NodeJs/web-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/home/trijay/Desktop/NodeJs/web-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/trijay/Desktop/NodeJs/web-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
```

Below is my code for app.js and also I have installed the hbs, express library. Any help will be appreciated

//app.js

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')


const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, '../public')   //for accessing comeplete file

const app = express()   //express being initialised


app.use(express.static(publicPath))
app.set('view engine', 'hbs')    //use to set handle bars. we need to provide key value pair

app.get('', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index')             //need to provide the hbs file name which you will find in view
})


app.get('/weather', (req, res) => {
    res.send({
        latitude: -57.89,
        longitude: 78.42,
        location : 'New Delhi'
    })

})

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server Started on port 3000')
})
```

Comment: What is the hierarchy of your project? like .. show us where is public relative to app.js

Comment: @MED https://i.stack.imgur.com/urGYg.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `views` directory to the engines options:

```
app.set('view engine', 'hbs') 
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../views'));
```

As you can see in the error message:

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "/home/trijay/Desktop/NodeJs/web-server/src/views"
```

`res.render('index')` points somewhere in `src` directory.

Comment: Thanks it works.  Earlier I mentioned this in my code but somehow it didn't work but now it's working perfectly fine. Anyways thanks you everyone for helping out

Answer (score 0):

I think you may forgot to setup the engine after defining it.

```
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.engine( 'hbs', hbs( {
  extname: 'hbs',
  defaultView: 'index' //your default template
}));
```

Try this and let me know.

Comment: fixed it with the help of kgmt